# What would be the sum of following?

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

How to calculate the sum of following:

$$n + 2(n-1) + 3(n-2) + \cdots + n$$

The sum neither seems to fit standard definition of AP nor GP.

Like $$1 + 2 + \cdots +n = n(n+1)/2$$

Comment: is the difference of two APs

Comment: Evaluate it for a bunch of n. And by the way, it is not an equation (there is no =), it is an expression. Please use MathJax in the future.

Comment: What you've posted is **not** an equation.  It's a sum.  Just like $1+2$ is not an equation, but rather a sum.

Comment: Hint: write the general term as $k(n-k+1)$ then sum them up.

Comment: You may consider that by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), or just by differentiation,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.\tag{A}$$
Let us square both sides:
$$\left(\sum_{n\geq 1} n x^n\right)^2 = \sum_{m,n\geq 1} mn x^{m+n} = \sum_{s\geq 2}x^s\sum_{k=1}^{s-1}k(s-k)=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^4}. \tag{B}$$
You may notice that your sum turns out to be the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in $\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^4}$, i.e. the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{x}{(1-x)^4}$. By stars and bars again, this is just $\binom{n+2}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that this sum is, more explicitly,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(n-k+1)$$ Manipulate:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(n-k+1)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-k^2 + kn + k)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-k^2) + \sum_{k=1}^n kn + \sum_{k=1}^n k$$

$$-\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + n \sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^n k$$
$$-\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + (n +1)\sum_{k=1}^n k$$

$$-\frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}6 + (n+1) \frac{n(n+1)}2$$

$$\frac{n (n + 1) (n + 2)}6$$